# Information not being received from server?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

Okay, my problem is very simple. Below is my code that is receiving prices from an API, in my code I want the today current price to be displayed, yesterdays price, and the change in percent from yesterday to today. Unfortunately, only the current price is showing properly, but the yesterday and the percent change just show N/A.

Any help is appreciated!

```
if (refreshing) return;
refreshing = YES;

UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

//self.priceLabel.text = @"Loading...";
//self.yesterdayLabel.text = @"Loading...";
//self.changeLabel.text = @"Loading...";

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate"]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^ (NSURLResponse *req, NSData *recv, NSError *err) {
    if (err) {
        // report
        [self setCurrentPrice:@"N/A"];
        refreshing = NO;
        return;
    }
    NSError *newError = nil;
    NSDictionary *serial = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:recv options:0 error:&newError];
    if (newError) {
        // report
        [self setCurrentPrice:@"N/A"];
        refreshing = NO;
        return;
    }
    NSString *amount = [serial objectForKey:@"amount"];
    NSString *price = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", amount, [serial objectForKey:@"currency"]];
    [self setCurrentPrice:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", price]];
    // maybe setup a better method.
    float diff = [yesterdaysPrice floatValue];
    if (diff == 0.0)
        self.differenceInPrices = @"N/A";
    else {
        float amt = [amount floatValue];
        float percentChange = amt/diff;

        if ((diff == 0) || (amt == diff))
            percentChange = 0.00;
        percentChange *= 100.00;
        self.differenceInPrices = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%%", percentChange];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *saveState = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"] mutableCopy];
    [saveState setObject:price forKey:@"price"];
    [saveState setObject:yesterdaysPrice forKey:@"lastCheckedPrice"];
    NSDateComponents *compon = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSUndefinedDateComponent) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [saveState setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (usingYesterdaysPrices ? [[saveState objectForKey:@"day"] intValue] : [compon day])] forKey:@"day"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:saveState forKey:@"save"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    self.priceLabel.text =self.currentPrice;
    self.yesterdayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yesterdaysPrice];
    self.changeLabel.text = differenceInPrices;

    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm:ss aa"];

    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
    NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];

    lstUpdate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Updated: %@ at %@", theDate, theTime];

    refreshing = NO;

}];
```

I also have this code in my viewDidLoad,

```
[super viewDidLoad];
refreshing = NO;
NSDictionary *save = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"];
if (save) {
    int timeStamp = [[save objectForKey:@"day"] intValue];
    NSDateComponents *compon = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSUndefinedDateComponent) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    if ([compon day] != timeStamp) {
        usingYesterdaysPrices = YES;
        yesterdaysPrice = [save objectForKey:@"lastCheckedPrice"];
        if (!yesterdaysPrice) {
            yesterdaysPrice = @"N/A";
        }
    }
}
else {
    yesterdaysPrice = @"N/A";
}
self.differenceInPrices = @"N/A";
[self sendNewRequest:nil];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(sendNewRequest:) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. Show the JSON you get back. Provide more details on what you works and what doesn't. There is no way for anyone to know what your code does without knowing what data you are processing.

Comment: Side notes - you are doing several things wrong in the code. Never check to see if something worked or not by looking at the error variable. Usually an API returns `nil` for some other value (or return value) and then and only then should the error result be looked at. You also have some pointless uses of `stringWithFormat:`. Only use that when you actually need to format a string.

Comment: I haven't tried anything different. I'm trying to call the current price from the API which is working fine. I'm trying to store the price after 24 hours and show that as yesterday's price and then get the percent change of those two values.